# Google search console reports URLs blocked by robots.txt even though they shouldn't be

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, robots.txt

Recently I sent a sitemap to Google Search Console and I got some warnings saying that some urls are blocked by the robots.txt. I checked it and there is no single line that blocks the corresponding URLs.

However all the URLs shown in warning start with dash `-` character.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Account/
Disallow: /random/
Disallow: /Random/
Disallow: /create/
Disallow: /login/
Disallow: /Login/
Disallow: /Edit/
Disallow: /edit/
```

This is my up-to-date robots.txt. Is there something about dash ("-") character related to robots.txt?

[image: Screenshot of warning panel]

**Update:** The issue is solved without us doing nothing. It turns out that even though Google Search Console shows everything okay, robots.txt is not updated internally for a while. It took 16 days to "really" update it.

Comment: Can you put the screenshot of the warnings? It will be helpful.

Comment: @Aakash did it.

Comment: "all the urls shown in warning start with dash" - all the URLS in your screenshot appear to start `/watch/--`? Has your robots.txt file changed in this time?

Comment: Are these valid URLs for your site?? Are they really in your sitemap? If so, check the source code of these pages for a reference that is blocked. It may not be the page per se' but a reference on the page. Otherwise, if these are not valid URLs, you may have another problem.

Comment: @w3dk You are right. What I was trying to say is that all the problematic urls are like "watch/--" or "watch/-" . If it is not a dash after the watch directory then everything is fine.

Comment: Try the same URLs in the "Fetch as Googlebot" tool in Google Search Console. Do you get the same "blocked by robots.txt" result?

Comment: @w3dk As a matter of fact. I tried robots.txt test tool of Search Console and it says "allowed" for those urls. They are allowed. But the warning remains the same although I resubmitted the sitemap couple of times.

Comment: Either Google has a bug, or your robots.txt file has changed.   If you did change your robots.txt, it can take a couple months for Google Search Console to stop reporting errors.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I resubmitted and tested the robots.txt multiple times, All the urls in sitemap (without exception) are passed as allowed. I believe this is a bug because of two reasons. First, It doesn't make sense when "watch/{sometext}" is okay while "watch/--{sometext}" is not. Second, Google is not crawling those urls with warning when we examine the visitors history of the website.

Comment: So, to clarify, the contents of `robots.txt` has not changed at all in this time period (several months)?

Comment: @w3dk Looking at the server history I can say it has changed 16 days ago. And there is in fact "/watch/" directory in it (don't ask why). But the point is, for the last 16 days robots.txt is as I stated in the queston. This is for sure.